# Anchor tags overlapping when the browser is sized to small

Tags: html, css

Ok, here is the issue I am having. I am hoping to seek some guidance on this. I am sure I am doing something wrong, but what that something is I don't know. I have attached two screen shots to show what I am doing here. The second one will show the anchor tags, which are display: inline at the moment overlapping each other when the browser window is to small.

**** CORRECTLY DISPLAYED ****
[image]

**** INCORRECTLY DISPLAYED **** 
[image]

```
#linkWrapper A {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px dashed #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
     -moz-border-radius: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30pt;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you dont post the html, my wild guess would be that the `height` CSS property does not suffice the whole button height.

So instead, use

**CSS**

```
#linkWrapper A {
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

It is a good habit to include the `line-height` property for cross browser compability.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is try to use it on % for height and width which helps lots of time, along with issues

about your issue, when screen in decreased the div or span font-size will remain as it is, that's why you will see two line one above and below, you can use @media query in CSS which help you in customizing for different screen width and height variant

```
  @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 850px) {

   #linkWrapper A {
padding: 10px;
border: 5px dashed #fff;
border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px; 
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
margin: 0 auto;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 30pt;
display: inline;
}
}
```

NOTE:

above css i have just copied and pasted, please change the css properties as you desired, so as above you can give for any width size screens

let me know if you have trouble